# rosinstall upstream

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know if .rosinstall can be used to pull from upstream. In doing so, we can get the latest changes from upstream as opposed to local changes that we create from within our own repository...

Is it possible? If so, what is the syntax?

---

Edit: @al-dev I feel familiar with wtool and its documentation.

The situation is that currently in my git folder I have an address for an upstream remote and an origin remote. wstool seems to compare the uri in the file to that of the origin master remote branch.

When I use wstool I get an error stating that the address in the file and that of my git repository are different...

> Prepare updating
> https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/baxter_examples.git
> (version master) to
> /home/vmrguser/ros/indigo/baxter_ws/src/baxter_examples
> Url
> https://github.com/birlrobotics/baxter_examples.git
> does not match
> https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/baxter_examples.git
> requested.

Feedback is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229316/rosinstall-upstream/) by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Juan, you can use `wstool` for that purpose. See http://wiki.ros.org/wstool for the syntax.
Typically, once you have properly configured your list of repositories in your .rosinstall file with their remote URI, you can pull with `wstool update` in the folder where your file is located (http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosinstall/html/rosws.html#update)

**Edit:** Now I understand your problem seems related to the fact that `wstool` uses the `origin` remote by default. You may want to have a look at [this ticket](https://github.com/vcstools/wstool/issues/59) and the discussion therein. In short the suggestions so far are :

1. try using `vcstool` instead of `wstool`
2. try out [this WIP branch](https://github.com/vcstools/vcstools/tree/allow_other_remote) if you are willing to keep only one remote, or
3. make a patch yourself and a pull request...

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1